# Java library for Raw Ethernet

Tags: java, ethernet, raw-ethernet

I'm looking for a Java library that will give me access to raw Ethernet frames, both for reading and sending them.  My end goal is to create a BACnet Ethernet network scanner.

Please, Note, I'm not looking for TCP\IP.

Anyone know of a good library for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc) can help. Notice that there's a Sourceforge project with the same name, but it doesn't seem to be the same project.

Here's some sample code (from the library's tutorial) that uses Jpcap to send a TCP packet and an Ethernet frame:

Edit: The sample code does create a `TCPPacket`, but you may create a regular `Packet` instead.

```
//open a network interface to send a packet to
JpcapSender sender=JpcapSender.openDevice(devices[index]);

//create a TCP packet with specified port numbers, flags, and other parameters
TCPPacket p=new TCPPacket(12,34,56,78,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,10,10);

//specify IPv4 header parameters
p.setIPv4Parameter(0,false,false,false,0,false,false,false,0,1010101,100,IPPacket.IPPROTO_TCP,
  InetAddress.getByName("www.microsoft.com"),InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"));

//set the data field of the packet
p.data=("data").getBytes();

//create an Ethernet packet (frame)
EthernetPacket ether=new EthernetPacket();
//set frame type as IP
ether.frametype=EthernetPacket.ETHERTYPE_IP;
//set source and destination MAC addresses
ether.src_mac=new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)1,(byte)2,(byte)3,(byte)4,(byte)5};
ether.dst_mac=new byte[]{(byte)0,(byte)6,(byte)7,(byte)8,(byte)9,(byte)10};

//set the datalink frame of the packet p as ether
p.datalink=ether;

//send the packet p
sender.sendPacket(p);

sender.close();
```