# How Can I Create a MAC Connection in Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java, network-programming

Anyone knows how can I create a connection without help of IP? Something like Winbox connection?  Is it possible to create socket connection by means of MAC address?

Comment: If you have the MAC address, why not just resolve it to an IP address?

Comment: Please explain your use case a bit more. Are you on an ethernet connection? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574036/java-library-for-raw-ethernet) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854961/best-way-to-do-raw-socket-programming-involving-java) question.

Comment: Java Sockets and DatagramSockets seem to work at Application Layer and Transport Layer of TCP/IP model in OSI architecture. What you are asking (host-to-network layer) is more at Network Layer and Physical Layer which Java networking doesn't provide any software interface for this. http://books.google.com.my/books?id=NyxObrhTv5oC&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=Java+networking+at+Physical+layer&source=bl&ots=1ebSrCSlSS&sig=pt8GA0MdRxvVX9gcXMHWf_Kv0Qo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ohU3T5nDHYqJhQfS5cShAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Java%20networking%20at%20Physical%20layer&f=false

Comment: What you are trying to do is better suited for pcap library. Java has a pcap library http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this may be an overkill, and I'm sure there are much better opinions, but just to get some of the job done, you may look at WinPcap and it's perfect .NET wrapper Pcap.net.

You may inject (and capture) any packet using your network card, and you can easily build any packet that fits your need. I'm sure such a thing would require something more low-level than, say, sockets programming, that's why I recommend using Pcap, if no better solution is found.